# Set default value of radio button in listview

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, radio-button

I have two radio buttons in a Listview like below

```
<ListView Name="ListBoolOption"
          Height="auto">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="pilganStack"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10,10,10,10"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <WebView
                            x:Name="option"
                            MaxWidth="600"
                            MaxHeight="300
                            Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="trueFalseStack"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="10,10,10,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Width="80" 
                            Height="35" 
                            BorderBrush="#2599FF" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
                                <RadioButton x:Name="benarBtn"
                                    Content="BENAR" 
                                    Tag="benar"
                                    GroupName="{Binding}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Margin="5,0,0,0"
                             Width="80" 
                             Height="35" 
                             BorderBrush="#2599FF" 
                             BorderThickness="1" 
                             CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
                                <RadioButton x:Name="salahBtn"
                                    Content="SALAH" 
                                    Tag="salah"
                                    GroupName="{Binding}"/>
                     </Border>
                 </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I want the default value of the radio button to be like a string

```
string a = "1:1:0"
```

How do I set the default value according to the string above?
Note:

- If the string is 1, then the value on the radio button is "benar". Whereas if 0, then the value is "salah"
- The meaning of the string is 1 which in the first character is the value of the radio button at the first index is "benar", for 1 in the third character is the value of the radio button at the second index is true, for 0 in the fifth character is the value of the radio button on the third index is "salah"

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to create a custom [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-22621) to implement what you want. It could convert the source value to what you need to based on the parameter you gave.

1. First you will need to convert the string into a list contains the data for the ListView
2. Then you need to use the converter to convert the binding value to different bool values for the RadioButton. You could pass the content of the RadioButton to the Converter so we could know which RadioButton is using now.

I've created a simple demo based on your code. You could refer to it:

**MyValueConverter.cs**

```
 public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //get target string index. 
        string parameterStr = parameter as string;

        //get target string like 1 or 0
        string valueStr = value as string;

        if (parameterStr.Equals("BENAR") && value.Equals("1"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (parameterStr.Equals("BENAR") && value.Equals("0"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (parameterStr.Equals("SALAH") && value.Equals("1"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (parameterStr.Equals("SALAH") && value.Equals("0"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**MainPage.cs:**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        List<string> source = getDataFromString("1:1:0");
        ListBoolOption.ItemsSource = source;
    }


    public List<string> getDataFromString(string sourceStr) 
    {
        List<string> itemvalues = new List<string>();

        string[] words = sourceStr.Split(":");
        itemvalues = words.ToList();

        return itemvalues;
    }
}
```

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
  <ListView
                                Name="ListBoolOption"
                                Height="auto">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel
                                                x:Name="trueFalseStack"
                                                Margin="10,10,10,0"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                CornerRadius="15,15,15,15"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border 
        Width="80" 
        Height="35" 
        BorderBrush="#2599FF" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
        <RadioButton
            x:Name="benarBtn"
            Content="BENAR" 
            Tag="benar"
            IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter},ConverterParameter=BENAR}"
            />
    </Border>
<Border
    Margin="5,0,0,0"
    Width="80" 
    Height="35" 
    BorderBrush="#2599FF" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    CornerRadius="10,10,10,10">
    <RadioButton
        x:Name="salahBtn"
        Content="SALAH" 
        Tag="salah"
        IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyValueConverter},ConverterParameter=SALAH}"
        />
</Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The meaning of the `string a ="1:1:0"` is that the number of indexes in the listview is 3 and for 1 in the first character the string is "benar" in the radio button for the first index in the listview, character 1 in the third character is "benar" in radio button for the second index in the listview, while the 0 character in the fifth character is "salah" in the radio button for the third index in the listview, like this picture: https://imgur.com/FmeU3KD

Comment: @cielo Do you mean you have three radio buttons in a listview item? If it is, you just need to change the logic of `MyValueConverter`. Remove the string result part.

Comment: @cielo What is your real scneario?

Comment: In a listview there are 3 items, each item of the listview has 2 radio buttons, namely "true" and "false" radio buttons

Comment: @cielo Do you mean one string "1:1:0" corresponding to three ListViewItems not a string for one item? Thre int values in the string corresponding to three Items(Two radio button each item)?

Comment: yes, it is right. if "1" is "benar" and if "0" is "salah"

Comment: I have tried the code above, but the application immediately exits and displays an error like this image: https://imgur.com/a/11bW2Ye

Comment: In the listview, it doesn't only contain 2 radio buttons, but also has a webview. I have updated the XAML in my post above

Comment: @cielo The webview does not affect anything. It isn't related to the binding. You should use binding for the IsChecked property of the RadioButton. The way you bind to GroupName is not correct. I've uploaded all the xaml I used which comes from your original post. Please try it in a blank project.

Comment: @cielo Have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: The application still force quit and appears like this image https://imgur.com/a/J0ENnY2. For listview there are 2 types of items, namely webview and radio button. For webview it displays string bindings from json

Comment: @cielo Are you still using binding for Group name of the RadioButton? Again, please use my code in a blank project

Comment: @cielo Maybe you could share the complete xaml that you are using.